# rails: what is the best way to track unique clicks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unique

I'm currently developing an affiliate tool with rails which is generating some unique affiliate links. I used to create those links via bitly and simply fetched the link-clicks through the bitly API. Awesome but if you delete your cookies, boom - click again and it counts again. So kind of useless.
I tried to familiarize with the google analytics api to count unique clicks but believe this is just overhead. Storing the IP address is also not the way I like to work.

Now I'm thinking to keep it simple and store the user's mac address in a database table when he clicks a link. The "stat model" is related to the link model and so I would find out which link was clicked by which mac address. If mac address exists already in the table for the link, don't count it.

Is this a proper way to solve my problem?
I read several articles where also mac addresses can be faked so I fear this can be hijaked in some way.
If you have any awesome ways to work with unique link tracking in rails, I would be curious to work with them.

Thanks for any help and tips.

Comment: How do you intend to get the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of a user's machine? That isn't available to you. You can get an IP, but that isn't necessarily the user's machine's true IP; It could be faked using a proxy, or changed by NAT. Assuming the user allows it, I think you're going to need to live with a cookie if you want to track clicks.

Comment: using the [macaddr](https://github.com/ahoward/macaddr) gem I can easily access a user's MAC address. Cookie is by far the worst option, you can simply delete it. Goal is that I don't want users to fake clicks by deleting cookies and hitting the link over and over again.

Comment: `macaddr` only gives you your local machine's MAC addresses (and basically relies on `ifconfig` to do it), not those of a remote user over TCP/IP.

Comment: You can't "easily access a user's MAC address" remotely. The networking protocols don't allow it unless you are on a local-area network with that machine (and even then you might not be able to depending on how the network is configured). Think about it, if there was a way to access the MAC address, don't you think thousands of other developers who want to track clicks would have done that, and wouldn't there be all sorts of tutorials on how to do it? The MAC address is only available remotely if you run software on the user's machine which then reports it to you.

Comment: sigh. So what would be the best way to solve my problem which is not easily fakeable?

Comment: @DonMB, I am having the same issue, did you get any solution or any gem/plugin for affiliate tracking tool in RoR?

Comment: Visitor tracking is a very complex topic, covered with thoretical and practical problems. I certainly believe it's out of the scope of a Q&A node.
If you're declining professional solutions (like Google Analytics, URL shorteners), your options become limited. You can still implement elements of click tracking, like the aforementioned IP tracking, cookies, etc.